# Lookup on a list with permissions

Tags: permissions, lookup-column

Is it possible to keep a list security trimmed to a small group, while allowing a list item column to be used as a lookup?  The purpose would be for the larger audience to be able to create a task that pertains to a task of the small group.  It would be nice to not have multiple lists to maintain, but I'm not sure how the permissions would work in this scenario.

This seems like a jumble of words.  If I need to elaborate more let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to accomplish this with one list, but I created a workflow to create an item in a new (placeholder) list with the column that I wanted.  From there I use the lookup on this placeholder list.  The permissions on the main list stay intact and I'm able to use the one column as a lookup still (via another list).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with active/inactive lookup field (for ex. employees). I added another field to lookup list (named active) and then use jquery to delete any inactive employees. In your case, the extra field would be the field that you filter. If this approach suits you, comment me to write also the code (jquery + Ajax).